# Why does this combination of GATs, lifetimes, and async require `T: 'static`?

Tags: rust, async-await, lifetime, generic-associated-types

This odd bit of code emits an error from `do_the_thing()` saying `T` does not live long enough:

```
use std::future::Future;

trait Connection: Send {
    type ExecFut<'a>: Future<Output = ()> + Send
    where
        Self: 'a;

    fn transaction<F>(&mut self, _f: F)
    where
        F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'a> + Send,
    {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn execute<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Self::ExecFut<'a> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn do_the_thing<T: Connection>(connection: &mut T) {
    connection.transaction(|conn| {
        Box::new(async move {
            conn.execute().await;
        })
    });
}
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
22 | /         Box::new(async move {
23 | |             conn.execute().await;
24 | |         })
   | |__________^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
20 | fn do_the_thing<T: Connection + 'static>(connection: &mut T) {
   |                               +++++++++
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=daa0dc400af06c7c11f93d4fdcd50563).

As far as I can tell, there should be no implied bound that `'static` is required. Pretty much everything is constrained by `'a` and any lifetimes in `T` should always outlive it regardless. Though obviously there might be something I'm missing.

I've also found a few "solutions" that aren't helpful:

1. Adding `'static` as the compiler suggests is not reasonable. It can be worked around but there are real `Connection`s with non-`'static` lifetimes that I would like to use.
2. For some reason removing the `Send` bound on the `dyn Future` makes it pass compilation. This makes zero sense to me.
3. If I make the function non-generic but use a `Connection` that is not `'static` it compiles as well, seemingly contradicting the compiler error.

The above is not real code; the original motivation stems from using [`AsyncConnection`](https://docs.rs/diesel-async/latest/diesel_async/trait.AsyncConnection.html) from the [diesel-async](https://crates.io/crates/diesel-async) crate and similar code structure. However, I hope it is representative of the core issue and that by understanding the problem and potential solutions here, they can be adapted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From further tinkering and research, I found this issue - [GATs: Decide whether to have defaults for `where Self: 'a`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87479) - in regard to the `where` clause on `type ExecFut<'a>`. From the comments in the issue, it seems others have had similar errors from having this bound enforced.

There's a workaround provided from the issue, which is to split your trait into two - one for the associated types and another for the methods so that the `where Self: 'a` clause can be omitted:

> #### This breaks my code. Workaround?
>
> First, if any code breaks from adding the required bounds, we really want feedback. Second, the workaround is to move the GAT into a super trait. Using the example above, our new code would look like:
>
> ```
> trait IterableSuper {
>     type Item<'x>;
> }
> trait Iterable: IterableSuper {
>     fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Item<'a>;
> }
> ```

Doing that on my example makes it compile but it does start to get messy in my target use-case.

Another workaround that I've seen mentioned was to introduce a dummy function that uses the associated type but not in conjunction with `self`. This allows you to omit the `where Self: 'a` clause as well, and thus the code compiles:

```
trait Connection: Send {
    type ExecFut<'a>: Future<Output = ()> + Send;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not need `where Self: 'a`

    fn transaction<F>(&mut self, _f: F)
    where
        F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut Self) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'a> + Send,
    {
        unimplemented!()
    }

    fn execute<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Self::ExecFut<'a> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    
    fn _disable_lint_for_exec_fut<'a>(_: Self::ExecFut<'a>) { }
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ dummy function
}
```

As a side note, there is another issue linked - [Problems with GATs, async, and Send-bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90696) - that describes an odd interaction between the bounds like above and `Send` which *may* explain why removing a `Send` bound caused the snippet to compile. Still weird.